# How to get Active Record query to return selection using filter (DataGrid)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, datagrid, filter, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a dashboard to display data using the DataGrid gem ([see it on github](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid)) in our Rails 4 app and a PG db.

In general the dashboard is working. We can for example search by typing in a symbol and it gives the correct info in the table below. So I know the top form_for is connecting to the bottom table.

The problem is I can't get the query to work for selecting and displaying the result(s) only with a specific score. This query returns all the values (all the securities that have all the scores). This is the filter(:aggregate_score, :enum ... etc. in the class AllScoringReport.

Controller for the dashboard:

```
class AllScoringReportsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @all_scoring_report = AllScoringReport.new(params[:all_scoring_report]) do  |scope|
      scope.page(params[:page])
    end
  end
end
```

Models for the dashboard:

```
class AllScoringReport

  include Datagrid

  scope do
    SecurityMaster
  end

  filter(:aggregate_score, :enum, :select => 0..10, :header => "Overall     Score") do |value|
    self.aggregate_score_score(value)
  end

  filter :symbol do |value|
    self.where(['symbol = ?', value])
  end

  column :symbol
  column :name

  column(:suitability_score, :header => "Price Volatility Score") do
    self.price_volume_scorings.last.suitability_score
  end

  column(:score, :header => "Instrument Score") do
    self.pl_instruments.last.score
  end

  column(:score, :header => "Overall Score") do
    self.aggregate_scores.last.score
  end
end


class AllScoring < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs to :aggregate_score
  belongs_to :pl_instrument
  belongs to :price_volume_scoring
  belongs_to :security_master

  validates_presence_of :user, :aggregate_score, :pl_instrument,    :price_volume_scoring, :security_master
end


class Grid < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope -> { order("grids.created_at desc") }

  validates_presence_of :code

  def file=(file)
    self.code = file.read
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

View for the dashboard:

```
%h3 Page Title
%h3

  %table.customer_information
    %tr
      %td.user_info_label Country:
      %td US
      %td.user_info_label Coverage:
      %td Top 20
      %td.user_info_label Updates:
      %td Weekly

%h4 Search By Category
.left
  = datagrid_form_for @all_scoring_report
  %br/
  = datagrid_table(@all_scoring_report, html: {class: 'table-bordered table- striped'})
  = paginate @all_scoring_report.assets
```

I thought about using array conditions described in the [Ruby doc for Active Record Query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) section 2.2 but didn't have any luck with that.

How can we get the filter(:aggregate_score, :enum ... etc.) to only display in the table those securities with the score the user selects from the droplist?

Note: We posted a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904123/correct-active-record-query-using-filters-and-dynamic-finders) for another query in this dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood this is the peace that doesn't work:

```
filter(:aggregate_score, :enum, :select => 0..10, :header => "Overall     Score") do |value|
  self.suitability_score(value)
end
```

siutability_score is a scope, right? Is it defined correctly? 
If you would run `SecurityMaster.suitability_score(10)`, do you receive what you expect? Afterwards try this:     `AllScoringReport.new(aggregate_score: 1).assets.to_sql`

If all things above return what you want, ensure parameters from a form are passing to grid class correctly:

```
def index
  @all_scoring_report = AllScoringReport.new(params[:all_scoring_report]) do  |scope|
    scope.page(params[:page])
  end
  raise @all_scoring_report.attributes.inspect
end
```

Comment: Thank you @bogdan-gusiev that pointed out a typo which we have edited above. We are not using suitability_score here. The filter we are trying to fix should have read:           filter(:aggregate_score, :enum, :select => 0..10, :header => "Overall     Score") do |value|
            self.aggregate_score_score(value) But we still have problems. The expected is to have user select a number from that droplist it returns only that score in the table. Instead it returns all scores. AggregateScore belongs_to SecurityMaster. It is not a scope. How can we make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
class AllScoringReportsController < ApplicationController   
  def index
    @all_scoring_report = AllScoringReport.new(params[:all_scoring_report])    do  |scope|
      scope.page(params[:page])
    end   
  end 
end
```

and on view index try

```
<%=@all_scoring_report.assets=%>
```